# A simple AI for Tic-Tac-Toe game

Tags: java, beginner, tic-tac-toe, ai

This is an AI class that takes an array of the board as an argument, and plays the best move after evaluating the board and gets a win rate. I haven't used any java package to do this. How can I make a genetic tree and calculate all possibilities for a given situation

```
public class AI
{
    int turn,ID;
    AI(int pID)
    {
        ID=pID;
        turn=0;
    }

    int getWinRate(int t[])
    { 
        int comb[][] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{3,6,9},{1,5,9},{3,5,7}} ;
        int AIwin,oppWin,empty,j,d;
        int WinRate = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)  //Count AI win combinations
        {
            AIwin=oppWin=empty=0;
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                d= comb[i][j]-1;
                 if(t[d]==2)
                 AIwin++;
                 if(t[d]==1)
                 oppWin++;
                 if(t[d]==0)
                 empty++;
            }
            //Changing win rate according to win conditions
            if(AIwin==3)        
            WinRate+=100;
            if(AIwin==2 && empty==1)
            WinRate+=3;
            if(oppWin==2 && empty==1)
            WinRate-=10;
        }
        return WinRate;
    } 
    void play(int t1[])
    {
        int t[]=t1.clone();
        int i,j,c=0;
        for(i=0;i<9;i++){
            if(t[i]==0)
            c++;
        }
        int[] moves=new int[c];
        c=0;
        for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            if(t[i]==0)
           { moves[c++]=i;}
        }
        int rate,boardcopy[]=t.clone();boardcopy[moves[0]]=2;
        int bestMove=moves[0],maxRate=getWinRate(boardcopy);
        for(i=0;i<moves.length;i++)
        {
            boardcopy=t.clone();
            boardcopy[moves[i]]=2;
            rate=getWinRate(boardcopy);
            if(rate>maxRate)
            {
                maxRate=rate;
                bestMove=moves[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The Mighty AI plays : "+(bestMove+1));
        turn++;
        t1[bestMove]=2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is some advice for your code.

#### General recommendations

1) For readability, I suggest that you change the way that you create your arrays; since the "C-style" array declaration is harder to read and less used in Java, in my opinion.

*Before*

```java
int y[] = {};
```

*After*

```java
int[] y = {};
```

2) In my opinion, I suggest that you wrap the logic of the condition / loop with braces, even if there's only one line of code; this provide consistency and prevent probable bugs if you want to add code to the condition and forget to add the braces.

*Before*

```java
if (t[i] == 0)
  c++;
```

*After*

```java
if (t[i] == 0) {
  c++;
}
```

#### `getWinRate` method

1)  Since the `comb` is always the same, I sugest that you extract it in a constant.

```java
public class AI {
   //[...]
   private static final int[][] COMB = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}, {1, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 7}};
   //[...]
}
```

2) Instead of using a series of `if` on a value that can have only one of the values, I suggest that you use the `if-else` or a `switch` statement and extract the evaluation of `t[d]` in a variable.

*Before*

```java
if (t[d] == 2)
   AIwin++;
if (t[d] == 1)
   oppWin++;
if (t[d] == 0)
   empty++;
```

*if-else*

```java
int currentValue = t[d];
if (currentValue == 2)
   AIwin++;
else if (currentValue == 1)
   oppWin++;
else //Zero
   empty++;
```

**or**

*switch*

```java
switch (t[d]) {
   case 2:
      AIwin++;
      break;
   case 1:
      oppWin++;
      break;
   default: //Zero
      empty++;
      break;
}
```

#### `play` method

1) In my opinion, instead of cloning an array, you can use `java.util.Arrays#copyOf(int[], int)`.

```java
   int[] t = Arrays.copyOf(t1, t1.length);
```

2) The `j` variable is unused.

3) I suggest that you use better names for your variable, it makes the code harder to read.

4) In my opinion, you can extract some of the logic into sub-methods.

a) Create a method to calculate the number of available moves.

```java
private int calculateNumberOfEmptySpace(int[] game) {
     int nb = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
         if (game[i] == 0) {
             nb++;
         }
     }

     return nb;
 }
 //[...]
void play(int[] t1) {
   int[] copyOfTheGame = Arrays.copyOf(t1, t1.length);
   int numberOfPossibleMoves = calculateNumberOfEmptySpace(t1); 
}
```

5) The index in the last loop is not used, you can use a `for-each`

*Before*

```java
for (i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
   boardcopy = t.clone();
   boardcopy[moves[i]] = 2;
   rate = getWinRate(boardcopy);
   if (rate > maxRate) {
     maxRate = rate;
     bestMove = moves[i];
  }
}
```

*After*

```java
for (int move : moves) {
   boardcopy = t.clone();
   boardcopy[move] = 2;
   rate = getWinRate(boardcopy);
   if (rate > maxRate) {
     maxRate = rate;
     bestMove = move;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what the actual question is, but I assume you want someone to review your code in a general way.

**You should always use explicit rather than implicit scoping.**

```
int getWinRate(int t[]){} //implicit scoping (not recommended)

public int getWinRate(int t[]){} //explicit scoping (recommended)
```

**Define single variable, field or method per line, for more clearer code.**

```
int AIwin,oppWin,empty,j,d; // not recommended

int oppWin; // recommended
int empty;
int j;
int d;
```

**Class names start with uppercase letters and fields, methods an variables names start with lowercase letters.**

```
int WinRate = 0; // not recommended

int winRate = 0; // recommended
```

**Define iterators in `for` loops, and if you don't use array index in the calculations maybe you should use [`foreach`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-each-loop-in-java/) function.**

```
int i;

for(i=0;i<9;i++) // not recommended
{
    if(t[i]==0)
    { moves[c++]=i;}
} 

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) // recommended
{
    if(t[i] == 0)
    {moves[c++] = i;}
} 

for(int i : t) // recommended foreach function
{
    if(i == 0) // i - is not a iterator, but a array member
    {
         // Do some thing with i
    }
}
```

Overall your code looks far to complex for it's simple task. Hope this helps you to improve yourself in coding.

I suggest you use [GitHub](https://github.com/) if you don't already use it, and than in the [Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace) page you should subscribe to [CodeBeat](https://codebeat.co/), [Codacy](https://app.codacy.com/) and [BetterCodeHub](https://bettercodehub.com/) apps for [automated code review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_code_review). It is free of charge for public repositories. It is very helpful.

Comment: I think your suggestion for the `foreach` loop is misplaced. Since the code uses both the value and the index, a `fori` loop is better suited.

Comment: @tinstaafl You are absolutely right. I will change it.

Comment: Thanks for you review @Zoran but does a 60 -line code which can play a game itself seem unsuitable .  Anyways is there a simpler way I can do this.

Comment: @AnmolAgrawal I will try to make the AI backend logic, and I will update my answer.